# Static member variables with same name in base and derived classes

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class Base {
   static std::vector<std::string> filter;

   virtual bool check() {
      if(std::find(filter....))
   }
}

class Derived : public Base {
   static std::vector<std::string> filter;

   bool check() override {
      if(std::find(filter....))
   }
}
```

Assume that both static variables are defined in their respective translational units.

I have a vector of static strings that carries the same name in the base and derived class because they are intended to carry the same type of info just with different values for each class. I know  name hiding for functions that are non virtual is not a good idea. Does the same apply to the static member variables? if so what are the alternatives?

Comment: You should probably start by asking yourself *why* you have the `filter` member in the child class. Why can't you use the one in the base class? Are they for different purposes? Or are they basically storing the same (or same kind of) data?

Comment: I have said in the question that they store the same kind of data! but not the same values

Comment: because they are values dependant only on the type of the class and not the instance of the class

Comment: Then they serve different purposes (as far as I can see and understand) and I don't see a problem with it. It *will* be confusing, but there's nothing inherently wrong. You might want to rename perhaps *both* variables to better fit each purpose better though, to avoid the confusion.

Comment: "*I know name hiding for functions that are non virtual is not a good idea*" - why do you say that? What bad thing happens in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all the same reasons to avoid shadowing non-virtual functions apply to (vacuously non-virtual) members;

I'm going to assume that the override of `check()` in Derived is textually identical to that of Base.

You can instead use a virtual method with static locals

```
class Base 
{
    // ...

    virtual /*const?*/ std::vector<std::string> & filter() 
    {
        static std::vector<std::string> value = ...
        return value;
    }
    bool check() // final
    {
        if(std::find(filter()...))
    }
}

class Derived : public Base
{
    /*const?*/ std::vector<std::string> & filter() // override
    {
        static std::vector<std::string> otherValues = ...
        return otherValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: yea i thought about doing the same. only to define the static value in the virtual function (check) directly would that work?

Comment: that gets you back to the "have to repeat the body of check everywhere filter differs" problem

Comment: @Robᵩ what is wrong with using `filter()` in all the places that `filter` was used?

Comment: My bad. I misread your code. Deleting my original, invalid, comment.